# JS class and functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello in my class match

in the construct I define my
isActive as false

because I want to use this to start a match and end a match

```
class Match {
    constructor(players) {
      this.id = uuid.v4().toString();
      this.players = players;
      this.isActive = false;;
    }

    startMatch(){
      this.isActive = true;
    }
    stopMatch(){
      this.isActive = false;
    }
  }
```

and I have my class matches 
in my matches class I create a match and add it to a match collection
:

```
const Match = require("./Match");
class Matches {
    constructor() {
      this.matches = [];
    }

    createMatch(players){
      this.matches.push(new Match(players))
    }


    getMatch(id){
      if(id){      
        return this.matches.find((match) => match.id = match )
      }else{
        return null;
      }

    }
  }
```

in my server:

```
const matches = new Matches();
matches.createMatch(player);
```

result this:

```
Matches {
  matches: [
    Match {
      id: '4a472acc-2a4e-465f-afba-fabbea2052e4',
      players: [Object],
      isActive: false
    }
  ]
}
```

But I'm wondering how I could change the status of a specific match within my match collection.

I also don't know if I did my class design the best way
if anyone can help me with this to improve classes

Comment: Use your `getMatch()` function to find the match and then call its `stopMatch()` function? Also, there's an error in the logic `match.id = match` should probably be `match.id === id `.

Comment: Yes i get an id just forgot to change in function kk

but I finding my match and calling the stop match or start match will work?

because I'm not passing anything as a parameter to this function

Comment: It won't work like that. You have to know which match you want to start/stop in advance, else you cannot stop a specific match right? I assume you will be adding code to the Match class that describes the game the match is associated with? When that game ends, the match should also end.

Comment: Yes so in case I have to pass the match as a parameter to my start or endMatch?

could you help me with this, i'm a little confused if you can make an answer for me to vote positive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bunch of ways to pass the parameters between the classes, so that kind of depends on other things, like if you use an event system, how tight the classes can be coupled to each other etc.

A 'simple' example would be this, where we pass functions ( callbacks ) between Match and Game, and between Matches and Match. The Game won't know or care what calling `finished()` will do, it just knows it should pass it the winning player.

```js
class Game {
  constructor(players, rounds) {
    this.rounds = rounds;
    // clone the player objects, adding a score to each.
    this.players = players.map( player => Object.assign({}, player, { score: 0 }));
  }
  play( finished ) {
    for( let round = 1, rounds = this.rounds; round < rounds; round += 1 ) {
      // random winner of the round.
      const random_index = Math.floor( Math.random() * this.players.length );
      const winner = this.players[ random_index ];
      winner.score += 1;
    }
    finished( this.winner());
  }
  winner() {
    return this.players.reduce(( winner, player ) => {
      if ( player.score > winner.score ) winner = player;
      return winner;
    }, { score: 0 });
  }
}

class Match {
  constructor(game) {
    this.game = game;
    this.id = Math.random().toString();
    this.isActive = false;
  }
  startMatch(finished){
    this.isActive = true;
    this.game.play( winner => {
      console.log( `player ${ winner.name } won with ${ winner.score } points` );
      this.stopMatch();
      finished( this.id );
    });
  }
  stopMatch(){
    this.isActive = false;
  }
}

class Matches {
  constructor() {
    this.matches = [];
  }
  createMatch(match){
    this.matches.push( match );
  }
  getMatch(id){
    if(id){      
      return this.matches.find((match) => match.id = match )
    }
    else {
      return null;
    }
  }
  endMatch( id ) {
    this.matches = this.matches.filter( match => match.id !== id );
  }
  startAll() {
    this.matches.forEach( match => match.startMatch( id => this.endMatch( id )));
  }
}

const players = [{ name: 'Alice' }, { name: 'Bob' }, { name: 'Carol' }];
const matches = new Matches();

document.querySelector( 'button' ).addEventListener( 'click', () => {
  const bestOfFive = new Game( players, 5 );
  const match = new Match( bestOfFive );
  matches.createMatch( match );
  matches.startAll();
});
```

```html
<button>Play</button>
```

If you so desire, you can move the `new Match()` and `new Game()` creation back into the constructors.

```js
// fake ajax request from the front end to the back end.
const ajax = function( payload ) {
  console.log( 'ajax call to the back end' );
  return back_end.request( payload );  
};
const front_end = {
  id: 'someId',
  render: function( content ) {
    if ( content ) document.querySelector( 'table' ).outerHTML = content;
  },
  makeMove: function() {
    console.log( 'Alice moves a white pawn from A2 to A3' );
    const move = 'A2 to A3';
    const result = this.sendToBackEnd( JSON.stringify({ id: front_end.id, move: move }));
    console.log( 'back end responsed, rendering result' );
    front_end.render( result );
  },
  sendToBackEnd: function( action ) {
    // this will be async, so look into promises
    // or use a callback as before
    return ajax( action );
  }
};
const database = [
  { id: 'someId', state: 'someWaytoDescribeState' }
];
const back_end = {
  validate: function( game, move ) {
    console.log( 'the move is one space down' );
    console.log( 'A pawn is allowed to move one down up' );
    console.log( 'The targetted space is empty' );
    return true;
  },
  request: function( payload ) {
    console.log( 'back end received request, recreating action' );
    const action = JSON.parse( payload );
    console.log( 'created action, searchign game' );
    const game = database.find( game => game.id === action.id );
    if ( game ) {
      console.log( 'game found, validating move' );
      const is_valid = back_end.validate( action.move );
      if ( is_valid ) {
        console.log( 'Move "' + action.move + '" is valid, updating database' );
        // insert database code
        console.log( 'database updated' );
        return `<table>
                  <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>B</td>
                    <td>C</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>tower</td>
                    <td>knight</td>
                    <td>rook</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>empty</td>
                    <td>pawn</td>
                    <td>pawn</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td class="move">pawn</td>
                    <td>empty</td>
                    <td>empty</td>
                  </tr>
                </table>`;
      }
      else {
        console.log( 'invalid move, board should stay the same' );
        return null;
      }
    }
    else {
      console.log( 'game not found, should send error' );
    }
  }
};

document.querySelector( 'button' ).addEventListener( 'click', () => front_end.makeMove());
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
}
td.move {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>tower</td>
    <td>knight</td>
    <td>rook</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td class="move">pawn</td>
    <td>pawn</td>
    <td>pawn</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>empty</td>
    <td>empty</td>
    <td>empty</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button>Make Move</button>
```

Comment: Could you ask me one more question?
Well I will create a game logic, where I will receive the game data from the front end and then decide a winner

I found the rounds logic interesting, but I will probably have trouble adapting it to the front end

who wins 3 rounds will win the game

Comment: What exactly is the question? The game can be anything, so the logic will depend on what you're playing. This game is just an example. And we can create bestOfThree by going `new Game( arrayOfTwoPlayers, 3 )`.

Comment: I really just have to do a logic

I think I'll have to store match data in the front end

and do a logic for when the 5 rounds are over

send everything to the back end

Comment: Simplest form would be to have the Matches and Match on the front end. Then send some players and the name of a game you have to the back end. When the back end is passed a game name and some players ( and any other parameters the game might need ), it can create that game and keep it in progress. Every time the player does something meaningful in game, send another update to the back end to update the game there. Once there's a winner, send it back to the front end.

Comment: My difficulty is to continue with the game in progress, I will not be able to use a loop

because then I could only have one match until it was over.

Comment: You send everything to create the game to the back end. The back end responds with the game id. The back end will have to store the game state somehow. ( database, files, in memory ) Every time the player does something that will change the game state, send the player action and the game id to the back end. The back end can then look for the correct game where ever it was stored and update it. Every update you can check for a winner. If the game is over, the response to the game update is the winner, if the game is still running, send something else as a response. That's the simple version. :)

Comment: And as in my backend I will do to know when a game state is changed using database and etc?

Comment: @gabriel I've updated my answer with a fake chess move.